# Google maps place search response sending invalid request back from server

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-places-api

I have a simple c# script that is trying to get the radar results from google maps place api. I created a key from the developer console (created it for server option, not console) for google places api.

Here is my https string

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/xml?location=37.778720,-122.441683&radius=8047&key=mykeyfromgoogle"

the xml response message I'm receiving says

```
<PlaceSearchResponse>
   <status>INVALID_REQUEST</status>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

Here is the simple c# script that calls it and the link to .Net Fiddle [**fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2OHed4)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Geocoding.GetCoordinates(null);
    }
}

public class Geocoding
{
    public static GeocoderCoordinates GetCoordinates(string region)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/xml?location=37.778720,-122.441683&radius=8047&key=myplaceskey"); //&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                XDocument document = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(stream));

                //XElement longitudeElement = document.Descendants("lng").FirstOrDefault();
                //XElement latitudeElement = document.Descendants("lat").FirstOrDefault();

                //if (longitudeElement != null && latitudeElement != null)
                //{
                //    return new GeocoderCoordinates
                //    {
                //        Longitude = Double.Parse(longitudeElement.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                //        Latitude = Double.Parse(latitudeElement.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                //    };
                //}
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class GeocoderCoordinates
{
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}, {1}", Latitude, Longitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem.. did you run the code and step thru it.. can you tell us what the question is.. and where the problem and or issue is occurring in  your existing code...?

Comment: when I look at the returned value 'document' in my script it shows 'INVALID_REQUEST'. It's not returning any results. Please make sure you understand and read my thread first before posting

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#RadarSearchRequests): ***A Radar Search request must include at least one of keyword, name, or types.***

You didn't include any of these parameters.

Comment: oh, I see. The documentation is misleading. It shows required parameters above but then it says you have to have at least one of the optional parameters. Weird verbiage. Thanks!

Comment: It's not easy to put them in the right place, when they define them as required it's misleading too, because none of these parameters is required.